How do I filter my data by a specific field in a record in my canvas app?
I am currently attempting to filter a list of records by data that will be located in a lookup field of each record. Think the overheard Portfolio is the main container, and the subsequent projects have a lookup field that details what project that task is attached to. I am not sure where to even start with the filtering to the lookup field because I keep getting errors. Note I just have 2 tables, Portfolios and Projects. I am a beginner at power apps so any assistance would be appreciated.
Here is where I am so far: to display just the specific portfolio I wanted, I have the following that worked: Filter('ABCTracker - Portfolios', 32 in 'PortfolioKey'). This then listed just the portfolio option I wanted. The next screen should be a list of just the projects in that portfolio.
The table I need to filter from is 'ABCTracker - Projects'. There is a field in this table that is called Lookup Portfolio. Every project is tied to a portfolio, and this is where that information is displayed. I need just the projects tied to the portfolio named Transformation Committee. I wondered if I can just use a text search for files that have the phrase above in it but not sure how to do that either. This is a shared Dataverse that I have minimal access to, hence why I need to filter things out so that users can only see what we want them to see.
